# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' how to solve this problem

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am facing this problem

> E/flutter ( 3688): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

I want to get data from the api in listview bilder. but this exception which i am not familiar with. How to solve it i donot know.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:learning_1ui_6228/utilities/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:learning_1ui_6228/utilities/helper.dart';
import 'package:learning_1ui_6228/utilities/widgets/app_line.dart';

import 'package:learning_1ui_6228/utilities/widgets/list_tile_widget.dart';

import 'package:learning_1ui_6228/views/nav_pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../model/UserModel.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  Future<UserModel>? futureUser;
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  // List<UserModel> userList=[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

List<UserModel> userModelList=[];
Future<List<UserModel>> getData () async {
    final response=await http.get(Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      for(Map i in data){
        userModelList.add(UserModel.fromJson(data[i]));
      }
      print('User Data list ${userModelList}');
      return userModelList;
    }else {
      return [];
    }

}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('user list ModelListdata + $userModelList');
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff8f8fa),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //1st Section
            Container(
              height: HelperClass.h250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: AppColors.gradientColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(HelperClass.r10),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(HelperClass.r10))),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Text and cross button
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: HelperClass.w10,
                        right: HelperClass.w10,
                        top: HelperClass.h20),
                    height: HelperClass.h50,
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.clear,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30,
                                ))),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            //  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            child: Text(
                              'Search',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: HelperClass.t25,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: HelperClass.h25,
                  ),
                  //Search Bar
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: HelperClass.w10, right: HelperClass.w10),
                    //color: Colors.amber,
                    height: HelperClass.h70,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: textController,
                      onChanged: (name) {
                        setState(() {
                         // searchUser(name);
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefix: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          size: 26,
                        ),
                        suffix: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              textController.clear();
                              //searchedList = userList;
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.clear,
                            size: 26,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // List View
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userModelList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(
                                       // userName:snapshot.data!.data![index].firstName??'',
                                        userName: userModelList[index].data![index].firstName??'',

                                        //followers: snapshot.data!.data![index].id.toString(),
                                        followers: userModelList[index].data![index].id.toString()??'N/A',

                                       // address: snapshot.data!.data![index].email.toString(),
                                        address: userModelList[index].data![index].email??'',

                                        //following: snapshot.data!.data![index].lastName.toString(),
                                        following: userModelList[index].data![index].lastName,
                                        //imageUrl: snapshot.data!.data![index].avatar.toString(),
                                        imageUrl: userModelList[index].data![index].avatar??'N/A',
                                      ),
                                    ));
                              },
                              child: ListTileWidgets(
                                following:userModelList[index].data![index].lastName,
                                address:  userModelList[index].data![index].email??'',
                                imageUrl:userModelList[index].data![index].avatar??'N/A',
                                name: userModelList[index].data![index].firstName??'',
                                followersCount:
                                'Followers: ${userModelList[index].data![index].lastName}',
                                iconWidget: Icon(
                                  Icons.person_add_alt_outlined,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  size: 25,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            AppLine(
                                paddingLeft: 10,
                                paddingRight: 10,
                                heightLine: 1,
                                lineColor: Colors.grey),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
                else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }

                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my data model

```
import 'dart:convert';
UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
      this.page, 
      this.perPage, 
      this.total, 
      this.totalPages, 
      this.data, 
      this.support,});

  UserModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = [];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data?.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support = json['support'] != null ? Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['page'] = page;
    map['per_page'] = perPage;
    map['total'] = total;
    map['total_pages'] = totalPages;
    if (data != null) {
      map['data'] = data?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (support != null) {
      map['support'] = support?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }

}

Support supportFromJson(String str) => Support.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String supportToJson(Support data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Support {
  Support({
      this.url, 
      this.text,});

  Support.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['url'] = url;
    map['text'] = text;
    return map;
  }

}

Data dataFromJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String dataToJson(Data data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Data {
  Data({
      this.id, 
      this.email, 
      this.firstName, 
      this.lastName, 
      this.avatar,});

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['email'] = email;
    map['first_name'] = firstName;
    map['last_name'] = lastName;
    map['avatar'] = avatar;
    return map;
  }

}
```

This is my api call **https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2**

Comment: Can you provide the `jsonDecode` source code that you call here `var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should call `jsonDecode` only if SatutsCode is 200, not every time

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are reading a single map here.

Do it like

```dart
Future<List<UserModel>> getData() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
 
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    userModelList.add(UserModel.fromJson(data));
    return userModelList;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why decoding response before testing if StatusCode is 200?

Comment: good point, @Alaindeseine feel free to update moving decode under if state

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I think the problem is here:

```dart
Future<List<UserModel>> getData () async {
    final response=await http.get(Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      for(Map i in data){
        userModelList.add(UserModel.fromJson(data[i]));
      }
      print('User Data list ${userModelList}');
      return userModelList;
    }else {
      return [];
    }

}
```

`data` is a map according to the response, which is not iterable. In other words, you cannot do `for (var i in data)` since only Iterables can be used in such a format.
Instead, it looks like the entire data is ONE UserModel, and you should be able to just decode `data` itself as an UserModel. I didn't see multiple users in the API response.

Comment: I also think that problem is something there but I have no idea how to solve that @MMZK1526

Comment: Well why **MUST** you try to get a list of UserModels? Because the API response DOES NOT give you a list, only a single UserModel. Nobody can just make extra UserModels out of thing air.
The other answer seems to get the point and explained it better, basically, you only got one UserModel from the this API request

Comment: You can't state what is the type of `data` as we don't know what return jsonDecode function.

Comment: @Alaindeseine I am only saying for this specific API request. Of course we shouldn't make assumptions in production for robustness